# How to add my listed numbers together

Tags: python, list, sequence, element

What I am having trouble is this: "Total of the elements in the second list: 62"
How can I add every element in the "second list"? I got this displayed at the end: (45, 12, 5).  That's not what I want. I want the number: 62. This is my first question at stackoverview and I really appreciate the help from all of y'all.

```
sequence = range(5,25,4)
first_list = list(sequence)
print("First List:", first_list)
print("Elements in the first list:")
for element in sequence:
    print (element)
sequence_second = range(26,0,-7)
second_list = list(sequence_second)
print ("Second List: ", second_list)
for element in sequence_second:
    print(element)
add = (second_list [0] + sequence_second [1], + sequence_second [2], + sequence_second[3])
print(add)
```

Comment: btw the line `first_list = list(sequence)` will exhaust the `range` and `sequence` will be empty from then on.

Comment: @quamrana You sure about that?

Comment: Ok, my bad. My test showed that `range` just seems to restart once exhausted. Must have been thinking about a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sum function:

```
>>> sequence_second = range(26,0,-7)
>>> second_list = list(sequence_second)
>>> second_list
[26, 19, 12, 5]
>>> sum(second_list)
62
```

Comment: And of course you could also just do `sum(sequence_second)`.

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `sum()`.

Just do `sum(second_list)`.

If you want the sum of just the first 4 elements, then do this:

```
sum(second_list[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
add = 0;
for element in sequence_second:  
    add = add + element
print(add)
```

Outputs 62

Comment: Sure, you _could_ do that, but the `sum` function is much more efficient, and more compact.